# ElementCollection Using With PlayFrameWork

Tags: playframework, yaml

I have some classes which are related. One them is have another classes's object set. Like this,

```
 @Entity
 public class Serving extends Model{

@Required
public Item item;
@Required
public Float amount;
@Required
public Date time;

public Serving(Item item, Float amount) {
    super();
    this.item = item;
    this.amount = amount;
    this.time = new Date();
}
}

 @Entity
 public class Receipt extends Model{

@Required
@ElementCollection
@NotNull
public Set<Serving> servings;
@Required
DiningTable dtable;

public Receipt(Set<Serving> servings, DiningTable dtable) {
    super();
    this.servings = servings;
    this.dtable = dtable;
}

//order'ın totalın hesaplamak lazım.

 }
```

and i also have some yaml data to initalize this.

> Serving(ser1):
>   item : it1
>   amount : 1
>   time : 2012-04-05 12:10
>
> Serving(ser2):
>   item : it2
>   amount : 0.5
>   time : 2012-04-05 12:11
>
> Serving(ser3):
>   item : it3
>   amount : 2
>   time : 2012-04-04 13:10
>
> Serving(ser4):
>   item : it4
>   amount : 1
>   time : 2012-04-04  13:10
>
> Serving(ser5):
>   item : it5
>   amount : 0.5
>   time : 2012-04-04 14:00
>
> Serving(ser6):
>   item : it6
>   amount : 1
>   time : 2012-04-04 14:10
>
> Serving(ser7):
>   item : it7
>   amount : 1
>   time : 2012-04-03 16:00
>
> Serving(ser8):
>   item : it8
>   amount : 2
>   time : 2012-04-03 16:01
>
> Serving(ser9):
>   item : it9
>   amount : 1
>   time : 2012-04-03 16:30
>
> Serving(ser10):
>   item : it2
>   amount : 1
>   time : 2012-04-02 17:00
>
> Receipt(rec1):
>   dtable : tab1
>   servings :
>      - ser1
>      - ser2
>      - ser3
>
> Receipt(rec2):
>   dtable : tab2
>   servings :
>       - ser4
>       - ser5
>
> Receipt(rec3):
>   dtable : tab3
>   servings :
>       - ser6
>
> Receipt(rec4):
>   dtable : tab4
>   servings : 
>       - ser7
>       - ser8
>
> Receipt(5):
>   dtable : tab4
>   servings : 
>       - ser9
>       - ser10

When i tried to initialize this data it gives this error,

> 14:13:01,200 WARN  ~ SQL Error: 1364, SQLState: HY000
>   14:13:01,200 ERROR ~ Field 'servings_time' doesn't have a default value
>   14:13:01,200 ERROR ~ Could not synchronize database state with session
>   org.hibernate.exception.GenericJDBCException: Could not execute JDBC batch update

How can i resolve this problem?

Comment: is the comma in the `ser2` Serving a copy-paste error?

Comment: you're right it's my fault. the correct one is comma or dot?

Comment: now i changed commas with dot, but error still same...

Comment: try using the date in a canonical format `2001-12-15T02:59:43.1Z`

Comment: same error continue... But error continues with this statements

javax.persistence.PersistenceException: insert into Receipt_Serving (Receipt_id, servings_id) values (?, ?)
 at play.db.jpa.JPABase._save(JPABase.java:38)
 at play.test.Fixtures.loadModels(Fixtures.java:215)
 at Bootstrap.doJob(Bootstrap.java:12)
 at play.jobs.Job.doJobWithResult(Job.java:50)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In serving class constructor must be get date as parameter.

```
public Serving(Item item, Float amount, Date date) {
super();
this.item = item;
this.amount = amount;
this.time = date;
}
```

So i have to add this constructor too...

Answer (score 0):

You should annotate your time with:

```
    @Temporal(TemporalType.TIME)
    public Date date;

or

    @Temporal(TemporalType.DATETIME)
    public Date date;
```

Comment: Sorry read your question too quickly. Have you tried Codemwnci's suggestion?

Comment: I believe the default format is yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss  Try initialising your dates with 2001-12-15T02:59:43

Comment: yes now error is changed but still near...


19:03:07,552 WARN  ~ SQL Error: 1048, SQLState: 23000
19:03:07,552 ERROR ~ Column 'servings_id' cannot be null
19:03:07,553 ERROR ~ Could not synchronize database state with session
org.hibernate.exception.ConstraintViolationException: Could not execute JDBC batch update
 at org.hibernate.exception.SQLStateConverter.convert(SQLStateConverter.java:96)
 at org.hibernate.exception.JDBCExceptionHelper.convert(JDBCExceptionHelper.java:66)
 at org.hibernate.jdbc.AbstractBatcher.executeBatch(AbstractBatcher.java:275)

Comment: Have you checked your yaml is correctly indented and that there is no tab, only spaces?

Comment: Yes, i checked. :) and finally i found the problem, i'm writing it as an answer :)